# Is it OK to deploy a private app on Apple Business Manager and the same app as an unlisted App on App Store?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, mobile, app-store

We have multiple clients that we wish to provide our software to.

After much research, it is clear that the Apple Business Manager (ABM) is the logical way forward. However we currently have one client that does not have ABM and has no intention of getting it until sometime in the future. As a result, we are forced to look at alternatives.

We have decided to go down the unlisted app route. In that, we will create a custom unlisted app through direct link. My assumption is that this will end up on the app store and will be available to them via a shared link.

My question is - is it ok for us to have an unlisted app as well as the same app on ABM (for our other clients) ?

This would mean that we have two apps to look after, one on App store connect and one on ABM? Both are identical apps so it shouldn't be too much of a problem. I am just worried that A) Apple wont like this and B) One app may interfere with another app.

Any advice greatly appreciated :)

Thanks!

Comment: Questions as to what Apple will do are basically off-topic, because only Apple knows what they will do, but I think you should be fine. If you spam the App Store with identical apps then you risk rejection, but these are two different, essentially private, distributions. They also don't know that there isn't some subtle difference in the ABM custom app and the unlisted app

Comment: @Paulw11 We have now found out that an unlisted app can also be put on ABM as well as app store. So in theory we should be able to just manage one app

Comment: An unlisted app is *kind of* in the App Store, but it cannot be discovered by search, only by a user having the URL.  You can, indeed, get unlisted apps via ABM, but all of your clients would need to get the app as an unlisted app; A single app cannot be both a custom app and an unlisted app.  Unlisted apps aren't as secure or controlled as a custom app where you nominate the specific customers that have access to your app.  Anyone who gets the URL can get the app.  For this reason Apple recommends that your app has some other controls, such as a login, to control use.